# React event binding when server rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I've a problem that's blowing my mind, I have a school project and I've decided to make it with Express and React. The problem is that I've a button and the event is not binding because of the server rendering.

I gave you the files below.

Button.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

class Button extends React.Component {

  clickEventHandler = (e) => {
    console.log(123);
    this.props.onClick(e);
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.clickEventHandler.bind(this)}>{this.props.Text}</button>
    );
  }
}

export default Button;
```

DataWrapper.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class DataWrapper extends Component {

  getChildContext () {
      return {
          data: this.props.data
      };
  }

  render () {
      return this.props.children;
  }
}

DataWrapper.childContextTypes = {
  data: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default DataWrapper;
```

Users.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Button from './components/Button.jsx'

var ModalHeader = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="modal-header">
        {this.props.title}
      <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
    )
  }
});

var ModalBody = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="modal-body">
        {this.props.content}
      </div>
    )
  }
});

var ModalFooter = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
    )
  }
});

var Modal = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="modal fade">
        <div className="modal-dialog">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <ModalHeader title="Modal Title"/>
            <ModalBody content="Modal Content"/>
            <ModalFooter/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

class Users extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
  super(props, context);
  this.state = context.data;
}

showModal(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
  //$(this.refs.modal.getDOMNode()).modal();
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row header-row">
        <div className="col-md-2 text-center">
          <span className="header-title">Pseudo</span>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-2 text-center">
          <span className="header-title">Email</span>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-1 text-center">
          <span className="header-title">Age</span>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-2 text-center">
          <span className="header-title">Nom</span>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-2 text-center">
          <span className="header-title">Prenom</span>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-2 text-center">
          <span className="header-title">Bannir</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      {this
        .state
        .Users
        .map((user) => {
          return <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-2 text-center">
              <span>{user.pseudo}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-2 text-center">
              <span>{user.email}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-1 text-center">
              <span>22</span>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-2 text-center">
              <span>{user.nom}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-2 text-center">
              <span>{user.prenom}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-1 text-center">
              <span>Ban</span>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-1 text-center">
              <Button Text="Test" onClick={(e) => this.showModal(e)} />
            </div>
          </div>;
        })}
        <Modal ref="modal"/>
    </div>
    );
  }
};
Users.contextTypes = {
  data: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default Users;
```

Router.jsx

```
    import express from 'express';
    import redis from 'redis';
    import request from 'request-promise';
    import React from 'react';
    import {renderToString} from 'react-dom/server';
    import {RouterContext, match, createRoutes} from 'react-router';
    import DataWrapper from '../client/data_wrapper.jsx';

    import appRouter from '../client/router.jsx';

    const routes = createRoutes(appRouter());

    const router = express.Router();

    let options = {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: '32768'
    }
    // The client stashes the password and will reauthenticate on every connect.
    let client = redis.createClient(options);

    client.on("error", function (err) {
      console.log("Error " + err);
    });

    client.on("connect", function () {
      console.log('Connected');
    });

    router.use(function (req, res, next) {
      if (req.url !== '/login') {
        client
          .exists(req.sessionID, function (err, reply) {
            if (reply !== 1) {
              res.redirect(302, '/login')
              res.end();
            } else {
              let token;
              client.get(req.sessionID, function (err, reply) {
                req.session.token = reply
                next()
              });
            }
          })
      } else {
        next()
      }
    });

    router.get('/', (req, res) => {
      match({
        routes,
        location: req.url
      }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
        if (error) {
          res
            .status(500)
            .send(error.message);
        } else if (redirectLocation) {
          res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
        } else if (renderProps) {
          const content = renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps}/>);
          res.render('index', {
            title: 'Express',
            data: false,
            content
          });
        } else {
          res
            .status(404)
            .send('Not Found');
        }
      });
    });

    router.get('/home', (req, res) => {
      match({
        routes,
        location: req.url
      }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
        if (error) {
          res
            .status(500)
            .send(error.message);
        } else if (redirectLocation) {
          res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
        } else if (renderProps) {
          const content = renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps}/>);
          res.render('index', {
            title: 'Express',
            data: false,
            content
          });
        } else {
          res
            .status(404)
            .send('Not Found');
        }
      });
    });

    router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
      match({
        routes,
        location: req.url
      }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
        if (error) {
          res
            .status(500)
            .send(error.message);
        } else if (redirectLocation) {
          res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
        } else if (renderProps) {
          const content = renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps}/>);
          res.render('login', {
            title: 'Login',
            data: false,
            content
          });
        } else {
          res
            .status(404)
            .send('Not Found');
        }
      });
    });

    router.post('/login', (req, res) => {

      let requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'http://MY_API/api/connection',
        body: {
          pseudo: req.body.Username,
          password: req.body.Password
        },
        json: true
      }
      request(requestOptions).then((body) => {
        console.log(req.sessionID)
        req.session.cookie.expires = 3600 * 24;
        client.set(req.sessionID, body.token);
        client.expire(req.sessionID, 3600 * 24);
        match({
          routes,
          location: '/home'
        }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
          if (error) {
            res
              .status(500)
              .send(error.message);
          }
          const content = renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps}/>);
          res.render('index', {
            title: 'Express',
            data: false,
            content
          });
        });
      });
    });

    router.get('/users', (req, res) => {
      let requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        uri: 'http://My_API/api/users/',
        headers: {
          "x-access-token": req.session.token
        },
        json: true
      }
      request(requestOptions).then((body) => {
        match({
          routes,
          location: req.url
        }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
          if (error) {
            res
              .status(500)
              .send(error.message);
          } else if (redirectLocation) {
            res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
          } else if (renderProps) {
            var users = {
              "Users": body
            };
            //renderProps = React.createFactory(renderProps)
            const content = renderToString(<DataWrapper data={ users }><RouterContext {...renderProps}/></DataWrapper>);
            res.render('users', {
              title: 'Express',
              data: body,
              content: content,
              users: body
            });
          } else {
            res
              .status(404)
              .send('Not Found');
          }
        });
      });
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

app.js(Express entry point)

```
    require('babel-register');
    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var nodejsx = require("node-jsx").install();

    var router = require('./routes/router');

    var app = express();

    // view engine setup
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');

    // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
    //app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    var session = require('express-session')
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(session({
        secret: 'schhhh', // just a long random string
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true
    }));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    app.use('/', router);

    // catch 404 and forward to error handler
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      var err = new Error('Not Found');
      err.status = 404;
      next(err);
    });

    // error handler
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      // set locals, only providing error in development
      res.locals.message = err.message;
      res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

      // render the error page
      res.status(err.status || 500);
      res.render('error');
    });


    module.exports = app;
```

.babelrc

```
    {
        "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"]  
    }
```

webpack.config.js

```
    var path = require('path');
    var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

    module.exports = [
      {
        target: 'node',

        entry: './client/app.jsx',

        output: {
          filename: 'app.js',
          library: "require",
          path: path.join('public/javascripts/')
        },

        module: {
          loaders: [
            {
              exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
              test: /\.jsx?$/,
              loader: 'babel',
              query: {
                presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"]
              }
            }, {
              exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
              test: /\.js$/,
              loader: 'babel'
            }
          ]
        }
      }, {
        name: 'client',
        target: 'web',
        context: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
        entry: {
          index: ['babel-polyfill', './users.jsx']
        },
        output: {
          path: path.join(__dirname, 'public/javascripts/'),
          filename: 'app.bundle.js'
        },
        module: {
          loaders: [
            {
              exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
              test: /\.html$/,
              loader: 'raw'
            }, {
              exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
              test: /\.css$/,
              loader: 'style'
            }, {
              exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
              test: /\.css$/,
              loader: 'css'
            }, {
              exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
              test: /\.jsx?$/,
              loader: 'babel'
            }
          ]
        },
      }
    ];
```

Help me please I'm becoming crazy

Comment: What do you mean by "the event is not binding"? Does it work when you're not rendering on the server?

Comment: console.log(123) is not printing ?? one more thing, you bind you event twice, by using `.bind(this)` and again by using arrow function `()=>{}`, in `Button.jsx` file, remove arrow use it directly like this: `clickEventHandler(e) {`, may be because of that it is happening.

Comment: No it's not printing... I tried removing arrow function it still doesn't work. And [Jordan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/179125/jordan) When I say the event is not binding, I mean the event is not present in the attributes of the button in the browser html. And yes it works when i render it only on the client...